# 'close' function on serial port descriptor blocks in linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux

Recently I've found a problem which is quite new for me and I'd appreciate advice. I'm doing serial communication on Linux using termios functions. I actually don't use real serial port, but virtual gadget serial driver `/dev/ttyGS0`. File descriptor is opened as non-blocking.

My program periodically generates data and sends it to /dev/ttyGS0. There is no information if the other end reads it or not. If it does not, some internal fifo fills up and write returns "would block" error. So far so good, I have no problems with that.

Problem is, when I want to close such file descriptor with filled fifo, close functions blocks! Not indefinitely, but for about 10 seconds.

I tried to do `tcflush(uart->fd, TCOFLUSH)` before closing without any effect.

This is so strange behavior to me and I found no description, that close could block. Is there any way how to avoid this? Or at least decrease this timeout? Where should I look for this timeout? VTIME attribute has also no effect to this.

Comment: close() maps to a call in the device driver which is where the delay is likely occurring.  If you have source code for the driver you can possibly modify its behavior.  Also look for any custom ioctl() calls supported by that device that might allow modification of the behavior.

Comment: It seems entirely reasonable to me that `close()` with data in flight would block - and I don't think the POSIX semantics of non-blocking IO extend to `close()` as well.  I would expect that after a `close()`, the device would be in a start where it was ready to be `open()`ed again. 

As this is virtual serial over USB, I would start suspecting a disorderly tear-down of the end-point, and the 10s being a time-out.

Answer (score 2):

As Amardeep mentioned, the close() call is handled by the driver.  Close itself is always a blocking call, but generally it's a fast one.

So, the answer is that the delay is specific to the virtual gadget driver.  I don't have experience with that one to help.

How important is it to close the file?  If the delay is a major problem and the file needs to be closed (such as avoiding file descriptor leaks in a long-running process), then the close will probably need to be called in a separate thread.  Obviously, the best answer would be one specific to that driver; perhaps research there might yield an answer, such as an ioctl() call that clears the state of the virtual device.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to configure your port's closing_wait parameter. From the setserial manual:

> ***closing_wait*** delay
>                 Specify  the  amount  of time, in hundredths of a second, that the kernel should wait for data to be transmitted from
>   the serial port while
>                 closing the port.  If "none" is specified, no delay will occur. If "infinite" is specified the  kernel  will  wait 
>   indefinitely   for  the
>                 buffered  data  to  be  transmitted.   The  default setting is 3000 or 30 seconds of delay.  This default is generally
>   appropriate for most
>                 devices.  If too long a delay is selected, then the serial port may hang for a long time if when a serial port which is
>   not connected,  and
>                 has  data  pending,  is closed.  If too short a delay is selected, then there is a risk that some of the transmitted data is
>   output at all.
>                 If the device is extremely slow, like a plotter, the closing_wait may need to be larger.

Check with setserial the parameters for your port:

```
$ setserial -g -a /dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyS0, Line 0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
        Baud_base: 115200, close_delay: 50, divisor: 0
        closing_wait: 3000
        Flags: spd_normal skip_test
```

In my case, a faulting device was not receiving the last bytes I sent it, and closing the port always took 30 seconds because of this. You can change this timeout with setserial, for example, to 1 second:

```
$ sudo setserial /dev/ttyS0 closing_wait 100
```

Of course, you may want to issue this command on startup in your /etc/rc.local or whatever script your distro uses to configure your ports.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, in my case disabling flowcontrol before closing the device helped. You can do this using following function:

```
int set_flowcontrol(int fd, int control) 
{
    struct termios tty;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0) 
    {
        perror("error from tggetattr");
        return -1;
    }

    if(control) tty.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;
    else tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        perror("error setting term attributes");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just call this before closing:

```
...
rc = set_flowcontrol(fd, 0);
if (rc != 0)
{
    perror("error setting flowcontrol: ");
    exit(-1);
}

rc = close(fd);
if (rc != 0)
{
    perror("error closing fd: ");
    exit(-1);
}
...
```