# Serial Port File Descriptor close() Delay

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port

I have an application that interfaces with serial ports. Sometimes when I close a serial port using `close(int fd)`, the call to `close()` takes 30 seconds or so.

Is there a way I can configure the system to forgo this delay when closing the file descriptor?

I open my port by `fd = open(addr, O_RDWR );`

Most of the code configuing the port is shown below:

```
   rc = tcgetattr(fd, &opts);
   if(rc) 
   {
      printf("TC get attr failed %d \n", errno); 
      return rc; 
   }

   // Configure parity
   opts.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
   if(com_port->parity_)
   {
      opts.c_cflag |= PARENB;
      if(com_port->parity_ >1) 
      {
         opts.c_cflag = PARODD;
      }

   }

   // Configure stop bits
   opts.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;                 // Clear stop bit for default setting
   switch(com_port->stop_bit_)
   {
      case 1: 
         //default is 1 stop bit for POSIX
         break;
      case 2: 
         opts.c_cflag |= CSTOPB;
         break;
      default:
         //Use the default setting for POSIX
         printf("Warning using default stop bit\n");
         break;
   }

   // Configure bytes size
   opts.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;                  // Clear byte size bit
   opts.c_cflag |= (CS8);                   // Set byte size bit

   // Configure flow control
   opts.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;                // flow control disabled
   opts.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;          // allow read and ignore ctrl lines

   // Disable canonical mode
   opts.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;

   // Disable echoing
   opts.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
   opts.c_lflag &= ~ECHOE;
   opts.c_lflag &= ~ECHONL;

   // Disable signal chars
   opts.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;

   // Disable flow control
   opts.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

   // Disable special handling
   opts.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL);

   // Configure output modes
   opts.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
   opts.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR;

   // Default timeouts
   opts.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;
   opts.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
```

I close the file with this code:

```
int CloseSerialPort(SerComPort* com_port)
{
  if(com_port->port_handle_ > 0)
  {
     tcflush(com_port->port_handle_ TCIOFLUSH); 
  }

  return close(com_port->port_handle_);
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to _edit_ your question and post more of your code. The code you've posted wouldn't account for the 30 second dealy. Unless you used `write` to put a lot of data in and the baud rate was _low_ (e.g. 300 baud). What baud rate did you set? You might be able to use `tcflush` (vs. `tcdrain`) to discard data that has been queued but not transmitted before doing `close`

Comment: looks like someone already had similiar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255314/close-function-on-serial-port-descriptor-blocks-in-linux/47799941

Comment: It seems like the question @JosiP posts has a solution outside of application code. Are you familiar with anything I can set within my application to get a similar outcome?

Comment: The `setserial` program uses the `TIOCSSERIAL` ioctl call and `struct serial_struct` to set the `closing_wait` parameter. I'd download the `setserial` program source and incorporate what it does. The struct is defined in `linux/serial.h`

Comment: Is setserial / TIOCSSERIAL applicable to USB "virtual" serial ports using the FTDI drivers?

Comment: FTDI has always been a bit weird. I'd say "probably" but try it and see.